# Gwt won't allow external Javascript = blank page

Tags: gwt

I am trying to include an external javascript file in my gwt project.In the files html page if I put the following with the external script before the gwt projects script I get a blank page and no errors.

```
<script language="javascript" src="my.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" src="com.mycompany.project.TESTPHONEGAP/com.mycompany.project.TESTPHONEGAP.nocache.js"></script>
```

However if I put the external javascript file after the gwt projects script it works.

```
<script language="javascript" src="com.mycompany.project.TESTPHONEGAP/com.mycompany.project.TESTPHONEGAP.nocache.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="my.js"></script>
```

I need the external script before the gwt script.What is going wrong here?

Comment: Is the my.js script tag in body of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to accomplish this using [Automatic Resource Inclusion](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion), where you put your `<script>` tags in your gwt.xml file. On page load GWT will inject this script before your `onModuleLoad()` method is called.